# datagridview text box column containing button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

[image]

regarding to above picture i want to have a datagridview by spacial column which have a button at left side.
Users can both type values in the text box or click the button to select value from a list.
when users click the button a new form appears below the selected cell.
is there any way to create any thing like this in C# windows form application?

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I didn't find any control like this.

Comment: what's your problem? is it to add a button to your gridview? or to get the values from the other grid view??

Comment: adding button to a text box column

Answer (score 0):

For Data Grid View control, you need to create your own user control which contains button and text box 
Next link show some example:  [Multiple controls in a single DataGridView cell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c28399bb-9d50-4a1e-b671-3dbaebb5cc69/multiple-controls-in-a-single-datagridview-cell)