# using button in datagridview text box column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridviewcolumn

[image]

as you can see in above picture i want to have a datagridview by spacial column which have a button at left side.

Users can both type values in the text box or click the button to select value from a list.

when users click the button a new form appears below the selected cell. is there any way to create any thing like this in C# windows form application?

Comment: this is a repetitive question the original is here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31085778/2374987

Answer (score 0):

Didn't tried but maybe this can help you out:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.100).aspx

Ps: Maybe create an context menu or something like a hotkey look easier ?